# BeautifulSoup - adding attribute to tag

Tags: python, html, tags, attributes, beautifulsoup

Question for you here, I'm trying to add an attribute to a tag here, wondering if I can use a BeautifulSoup method, or should use plain string manipulation.

An example would probably make this clear, as it's a weird explanation.

How the HTML Code looks now:

```
<option value="BC">BRITISH COLUMBIA</option>
```

How I would like it to look:

```
<option selected="" value="BC">BRITISH COLUMBIA</option>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Easy with BeautifulSoup :)

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<option value="BC">BRITISH COLUMBIA</option>')
>>> soup.find('option')['selected'] = ''
>>> print soup
<html><body><option selected="" value="BC">BRITISH COLUMBIA</option></body></html>
```

The attributes can be looked at as a dictionary. So we have `{'value':'BC'}`, and to add a value to a dictionary, we just do `dict[key] = value`

Comment: Great, thanks! While I have you here, if I've taken a page, searched through it for just these provinces, created a list of them. I'm finding that some of them are tags, which I want, and some are "Navigatable Strings" which all are "u'\n'", which I have no idea where they came from. Any idea for getting rid of them?

Comment: @KelanPoten-Coyle You could probably filter the list: `[i for i in the_list if i != u'\n']`. Or something similar. Or, you may need to specifcy your `find_all` search when getting the provinces (I'm presuming you're using find_all)