# Web Scraping - writing inside input tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

so lets imagine i have a website and it has a code like this:

```
<input class="js-search-input" type="text" name="q" (and some other useless attribute here)>
```

what i want to do is to write a code that scrapes this website and identifies this input (which in this case is easy to do with CSS Selector) and, i want it to **type words** inside the input tag for me. notice that i don't want to submit the page , i only want to type words there!
i already did scrape this website and it was fairly easy but this part really challenged me as i also found no specific google/youtube answer for it.

thanks for any help in advance.

Image of this website and its input : [Click Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N87k4.png)

edit: my language is python btw

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17497840/13219701) answer should hopefully help you

Comment: Thank you this was a helpful method but didn't work in my case for some reasons :(
I found the answer tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Selenium, if you need to render the page (it's neccessary for interacting with elements)
If you have just the code, you can analyse it, and find the form, that sends the request, and then simulate it's submitting.